# How to pick the desired trust certificate from trust store when there are multiple certs with same trustedX500Principals

Tags: ssl, certificate, trust

I have a server root certificate coming to be expired soon with SHA1, and got a new server root certificate with longer life with SHA256. We want to include both of them in our client trust store so that we can have smooth transition when prod environment switch the certificate.

We provide the trust manager in our code by loading the trust store through javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory, we then saw an error when run our client application:

```
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 128
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:189)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1222)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:655)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:444)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:392)
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:213)
```

The two trusted certs are with same issuer, but different expiration date and signing algorithms.

I found the root cause is that sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator only pick the first trusted certs in case there are multiple certs with the same issuer

The source code jdk's SimpleValidator show the reason, if there are multiple trust certs for the same issuer, the first one will always be used:

```
        // check if we can append a trusted cert
        X509Certificate cert = chain[chain.length - 1];
        X500Principal subject = cert.getSubjectX500Principal();
        X500Principal issuer = cert.getIssuerX500Principal();
        List<X509Certificate> list = trustedX500Principals.get(issuer);
        if (list != null) {
            X509Certificate trustedCert = list.iterator().next();
            c.add(trustedCert);
            return c.toArray(CHAIN0);
        }
```

I expect the there is a way to verify the server cert based on all the trusted ones with the same issuer.

Or a way to pick the right trust certs based on the issuer and the signature algorithm.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the server you are connecting to only responds with the Leaf Certificate. Super easy fix would be to request Server to respond with Full Chain ( Leaf + Intermediate + Root CA ) so that  java can grep the signature name/algorithm  directly from the certs presented.

If that is not possible then  while passing the server certificate chain into the validator, It needs to be  appended with  the desired trust cert into the chain based on the issuer and the signing algorithm name.
Refer : https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/sun/security/validator/SimpleValidator.java#L378

Comment: Can you clarify how it can "be appended with the desired trust cert into the chain"?

Comment: Something similar like  below - while creating the ssl context

Comment: Yes, you are actually right, eventually the server side did the fix as what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar like  below - while creating the ssl context

```
private TrustManager[] wrapLoggingTrustDelegate(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
    if (trustManagers == null || trustManagers.length == 0) {
        return trustManagers;
    }
    TrustManager[] result = new TrustManager[trustManagers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < trustManagers.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (trustManagers[i] == null || !(trustManagers[i] instanceof X509TrustManager)) ? trustManagers[i] : new SigNameMatchingX509TrustManager(new LoggingDelegateX509TrustManager((X509TrustManager)trustManagers[i]), trustManagerKeyStore);
    }
    return result;
}

private SSLContext getSslContext() {
    SSLContext sc;

    try {
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance(sslContextType);
        sc.init(wrapLoggingKeyDelegate(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers()), wrapLoggingTrustDelegate(trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error configuring SSL Context.", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error configuring the SSL Context", e);
    }

    return sc;
}
```